# Python updating DB column issue with overwrite?

Tags: python, database

I have a simple function which should update a certain column for certain users:

```
for key, group in groupby(list_i):
    print key, type(key), len(list(group)), type(len(list(group)))
    setattr(User.query.filter_by(id=key).first(), "number_of_rooms", len(list(group)))
db_session.commit()
```

I have a list (`list_i`) which has the data, simply look at the print:

[image]

The data is correct, the first number is the id of the user and the second is the value which should be assign to column `number_of_rooms`

The problem is it sets all values of the users to `0`. I assume it is somehow an override issue of the last user, I dont know. The thing is if I change it to:

```
setattr(User.query.filter_by(id=key).first(), "number_of_rooms", 2)
```

It will change the value to `2` for all users with `id=key` so the function works. I am here very confused, because `len(list(group))` is a simple integer and it should work.

**EDIT:**

I double checked everything, I also made an other test with a variable (`t`) which increments by 1 and added an onther print to check everything, with the variable it also works, how is that possible?

```
t = 0
for key, group in groupby(list_i):
    print key, type(key), len(list(group)), type(len(list(group)))
    my_user = User.query.filter_by(id=key).first()
    setattr(my_user, "number_of_rooms", t)
    print my_user.number_of_rooms
    t+=1
db_session.commit()
```

The value of `number_of_rooms` changes:

[image]

Comment: Try to save `len(list(group))` to any var before `setattr` and use this var, not function.

Comment: Its still the same @RomanMindlin

Comment: Ok, try to switch on echo and check SQL statements sent

Comment: I managed to solve it check my last update, probably you can explain this @RomanMindlin

Comment: Sorry, but I have to look to SQL statements to explain

Comment: What is `type(group)`?

Comment: 'type(group)' is '<type 'itertools._grouper'>' @glibdud

Comment: Yeah, everything is consistent with what Roman Mindlin suggested in his first comment: you need to save the result of `len(list(group))` (or at least `list(group)`) to a variable and then use that variable. After you iterate over `group` once (e.g. by calling `list()` on it), it's exhausted.

Comment: I tryed ´a_variable = len(list(group))´ and used ´a_variable´ in the ´setattr´. Still had 0's. Probably should have saved ´list(group)´. But you helped me to understand why this happened. So it got consumed because of ´list()´

Comment: If you answer the question I accept it

Answer (score 0):

As [Roman Mindlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361626/python-updating-db-column-issue-with-overwrite#comment79683613_46361626) and [glibdud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361626/python-updating-db-column-issue-with-overwrite#comment79688950_46361626) have specified, `list(group)` can only be used once. Since `group` is of type `<type 'itertools._grouper'>`, after you iterate over `group` once (e.g. by calling `list()` on it), it's exhausted. The key is to save the `list(group)` inside a variable.

Here is the code that fixes the issue:

```
for key, group in groupby(list_i):
    l_group = list(group)
    print(l_group)
    my_user = User.query.filter_by(id=key).first()
    setattr(my_user, "number_of_rooms", len(l_group))
db_session.commit()
```